# How to output piped stdout in bash script from getopts?

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection, xargs, getopts

I have the following snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash

OPTIND=1
while getopts ":m:t" params; do
    case "${params}" in

        m)
             bar=$OPTARG ;;
        t)
            foo=$OPTARG ;;

        \?) 
            "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
            print_usage 
            exit 2
            ;;

        :)
            echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
            print_usage
            exit 2
            ;;

        esac

done
shift "$(( OPTIND-1 ))"
echo "${foo}"  && echo  "${bar}"
```

How can I output the stdout using pipes through this script?

For example:

```
echo "this is the test" | bash getoptscript.sh -m -
```

And it should provide :
`this is the test` as the output.

Comment: Found the answer. Something like: `echo "Test" | xargs bash getoptscript.sh -m `. But is this "good" way?

Comment: So, you want the script to read stdin if the argument to the switch is a dash `-` and otherwise use the argument itself? That should be a simple test within the `m)` case, read from stdin if `OPTARG` is `-`, otherwise use `OPTARG` itself. I'm not exactly sure if this is what you wanted, though. It would seem more common to have dash as a filename representing stdin. Some commands have a different option characters for giving the literal value and for giving a reference to a file from which to read it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By piping the output to xargs, which converts its input into *arguments*:

```
echo "this is the test" | xargs bash getoptscript.sh -m -
```

Which will result in:

```
bash getoptscript.sh -m - this is the test
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than taking the string as a command line argument, you may simply use `cat` to read the script's standard input:

```
printf '%s\n' "$foo"
if [ "$bar" = "-" ]; then
    # assume data is on standard input
    cat
else
    print '%s\n' "$bar"
fi
```